# NSUserDefaults IOS Accessible Everywhere?

Tags: objective-c, ios, singleton, nsuserdefaults

I am wondering if the NSUserDefaults object is shared and can be accessed from within the app delegate as well as within several of my view controllers. Basically I need to pass data from the app delegate back and forth to the view controllers. I don't want to use a singleton. I was wondering if the NSUserDefauflts object was a way to do this.

If this is possible, how would I initialize the object so that is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: would a plist be better in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just use `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`, the same instance will be returned every time. Different classes can then use it to store data that is persistent across sessions.

If you're just trying to pass data between parts of the app, but not store it, user defaults are not the appropriate way to do so. You should expose methods or properties on your classes that take as input the data you need to pass.

Comment: +1 for being faster than me. Dependency injection is way to go, pass the data to classes that need it, and prefer custom initializers over properties for values that are required for the class/view to work properly.

Comment: passing to classes involves casting in my place from view controllers to app delegates... cuz i need some stuff to work in app delegate... id rather really just use nsuerdefaults because I will be using it anyway for other data storage... so i want a unified system sort of that view controllers can access


thx a lot though, [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] sounds really good... when are they initialized? are they always around? will it maintain data across different sessions? does it interact with the file system somehow?

Comment: @user1392515 That is covered in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Short answer is when you need it and YES.

Comment: @user1392515: It sounds like you're leaning toward using `NSUserDefaults` to pass data between objects. I can't stop you, but I can tell you that no good will come of it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it is but that's not really what it's designed for. The normal design pattern is to pass the objects back and forth between your view controllers "manually." You want your view controllers to be as independent -- reusable -- from the rest of your application as possible. Tying them to `NSUserDefaults` isn't a good way to do that!

Answer (score 2):

You should not be doing any processing in your app delegate.  Ideally, you should initialise your window, root view controller (if not doing it by storyboard) and model and that's it.  All processing should be done elsewhere (mostly in view controllers talking to the model classes).

Make your root model class a singleton so that all your view controllers can talk to it via an interface of your choosing.

Making a singleton is not hard:

```
@interface MyModel: NSObject

+ (MyModel *)sharedModel;

@end
```

and the implementation:

```
@implementation MyModel

+ (MyModel *)sharedModel
{
    static MyModel* modelSingleton = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        modelSingleton = [[MyModel alloc] init];
    });

    return modelSingleton;
}

@end
```

And then you just use:

```
[MyModel sharedModel]
```

to access it.

Comment: thx for the answer... but I'm scared a lot of singletons (i don't really understand them)

Comment: singletons basically provide a method or function to access the single object.  By doing it through a function or method, you can control how many instances of the object you create (in this case 1).  The dispatch_once stuff does two things: ensure it is run only once ever, and make sure that it is thread-safe.  This means if more than one thread calls sharedModel at the same time we still only get one instance.